# forward or reverse accumulation DL frameworks

Tags: backpropagation

Automatic differentiation can be accomplished using forward or reverse accumulation.

Quoting Wikipedia :

[image]

which mode is used in DL frameworks is used for implementation and why?
Does it have any motivation from the issue of complexity as in the above article?